# Menu customization questions in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a menu in C# Console app and I am trying to make it like this:

```
[1] Login
[2] Register
[3] Exit
```

But as you can see, I am manually inserting the number inside of the bracket, how would I make it so everytime I do
`Console.WriteLine(“test”)`
It would do it on its own like this:
[1] test

This has been frustrating me for a little bit.

Comment: No way, it can't do by itself. You could write a function that, given a text as parameter, writes it down to console using the convention you need. You could even use a static integer that could be auto-incremented... but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own method, which prints this indexes automatically.

```
public static class CustomConsole
{
    public static int Index {get;private set;} = 1;
    public static void WriteLine(String message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Index++}] {message}");
    }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
CustomConsole.WriteLine("Login");
CustomConsole.WriteLine("Register");
CustomConsole.WriteLine("Exit");
```

Comment: Fixed your code, 'cause it had several errors within the function and also Index was not properly initialized, so the wrong integer would have been printed

Comment: By the way, this is not an extension method ;)

Comment: Hi @Marco, thanks for your edits. Yes you are correct, it is not an extension method. I updated my answer

Comment: @xkazi, was it helpful?

Comment: Going to try it right now, @PrasadTelkikar